# how can I detect whether a specific page is mapped in memory?

Tags: c, linux, unix, mmap

I would like to detect whether or not a specific page has already been mapped in memory. The goal here is to be able to perform this check before calling mmap with a fixed memory address. The following code illustrates what happens in this case by default: mmap silently remaps the original memory pages.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int page_size;
  void *ptr;
  page_size = getpagesize();
  ptr = mmap(0, 10 * page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
             MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf ("map1 failed\n");
    return 1;
  }
  ((int *)ptr)[0] = 0xdeadbeaf;
  ptr = mmap(ptr, 2 * page_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);
  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf ("map2 failed\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if (((int *)ptr)[0] != 0xdeadbeaf) {
    printf ("oops, data gone !\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that I could open and parse /proc/self/maps to figure out which memory range has been allocated and infer from that if I can safely request a specific memory range with mmap but I am looking for a proper API: is there such a thing ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use MAP_FIXED and see if it succeeds?

Comment: Ha, my example code was incorrect (i.e., it is missing MAP_FIXED to the second mmap (just edited)). My point is that MAP_FIXED does not ensure that you get an error if the memory range is already allocated (you can run the code or read the relevant man page if you doubt this)

Comment: Btw, if you wonder what MAP_FIXED is good for, I do too :)

Comment: @MerickOWA According to the man page, `MAP_FIXED` will override the mapped pages: **If the memory region specified by addr and len overlaps pages of any existing mapping(s), then the overlapped part of the existing mapping(s) will be discarded.** So you should not rely on `MAP_FIXED`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

msync(addr, len, 0) and checking for ENOMEM seems to work (with a fairly superficial test).

Comment: NOTICE: for a unmapped page, `msync()` may return `0` or `-1` with `ENOMEM`, so it's not an accurate solution.

Comment: NOTICE: calling `msync` makes your app a *little* more stable, in exchange the whole system becomes much slower. Avoid all unneeded msync, best if you avoid all syncs, there are other ways to ensure app stability.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't "remap" the memory, but creates another mapping at different address (since the one you give it is already taken, and it's treated as a hint anyway). The old one is still valid, you just lose the reference to it since you overwrite the `ptr` variable.

If you want to create multiple mappings to the same memory like that look into [`shm_open(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).

<del>If you just want to check if address is mapped then the `MAP_FIXED` trick pointed out by @MerickOWA should work.</del>

#### Edit 0:

You are right about `MAP_FIXED`, it doesn't help in this case. What you might try is [`mincore(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mincore.2.html). One of the errors it returns is:

**`ENOMEM`**`addr to addr + length contained unmapped memory.`

Comment: 0) yes, "remap" is not the proper term but the problem here is not the fact that I overwrite the ptr variable (ptr gets the same value for both calls to mmap). The problem is that the previous memory mapping is gone after the second call to mmap. 1) I do not want multiple mappings. I just want to map something at a fixed address but before doing this, I want to check if the address is already mapped because 2) mmap does not return an error if the requested fixed address is already used for a mapping (the MAP_FIXED flag I had forgotten in the sample code above changes nothing to that)

Comment: mincore does not appear to be what I am looking for since it checks if the page is resident or not, not whether the address range is valid.

Comment: Yes, but you can use its side effect of reporting unmapped address.

Answer (score 0):

On QNX, you can use [`mem_offset()`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref%2Ftopic%2Fm%2Fmem_offset.html) and [`posix_mem_offset()`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref%2Ftopic%2Fp%2Fposix_mem_offset.html) and check the contents of `contig_len` on output, comparing it with the `length` input parameter.