# How to determine whether a memory page is mmaped in C

Tags: python, c, numpy, mmap

I would like to know a way to determine whether a pointer belongs to a mmaped memory page.

A [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362747/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-specific-page-is-mapped-in-memory) on StackOverflow suggest using msync() on the pointer to determine whether it passes or not. But what I found is msync() will success as long as the pointer is a multiple of the page size, no matter the page is mmaped or not.

I calculate the start address of the page by the macro:

```
#define align_to_page(addr,pagesize) (addr & ~(pagesize - 1))
```

Please help me, I have been working on it for a long time and blocked here. Thank you in advance :)

Background:
I am developing an extension to Python and Numpy. In some functions, it has to distinguish a normal numpy.ndarray and a numpy.memmap which is a subclass of numpy.ndaraay with its data buffer created by mmap() backed by a file on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-empty process address space is `mmap`ed. Either using `mmap` syscall or indirectly via `brk`/`sbrk` syscalls .

You probably need to find another way to distinguish `numpy` arrays.

[`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html?highlight=mmap#numpy.memmap) documentation says these arrays have additional attributes `filename`, `offset` and `mode`, may be you can use these to detect whether an array is backed by a file.

Comment: You are right. I found every page accessible from the process are mmap pages, either anonymous or backed by some file. I can apply function such as madvise or msync to every page in the data segment.

Comment: Your idea of distinguishing memmap by its special attributes works perfectly :D I take the "flush" method as a condition to determine whether it is memmap or not. It reminds me of how Python interpreter compare an object to a class definition.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do know the start address of your contiguous memory pool  and its size you just have to check you pointer:

```
if( (my_ptr >= start_addr) && (my_ptr < start_addr + pool_size) )
{
    return true; // my_ptr belongs to the memory pool
}
```