# How to check if memory region is mapped to file?

Tags: c, linux, memory, mmap, system-calls

Is there any way to check whether memory region is mapped to some underlying file using mmap ?

I mean I would like to write a function:

```
int is_mmapped(void *ptr, size_t length);
```

Which returns nonzero value for memory region which entirely mapped to file using mmap syscall.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362747/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-specific-page-is-mapped-in-memory

Comment: Yes I've seen this before. This problem is marked as solved but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I tried msync and there is no error value for memory allocated using valloc.

Comment: Using msync in this way is, as you discovered, non-portable.  If no such storage exists, msync() need not have any effect.

Comment: Any reason not to use `/proc/self/maps`? It's a documented interface on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

As [Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826372/ross-ridge) suggested in the comments, `/proc/self/maps` can help you with this.

Each line looks something like this:

```
35b1a1f000-35b1a20000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
START ADDR- END ADDR  PERM  OFFSET   DEV   INODE   PATHNAME
```

All we care about are the start and end addresses, so this doesn't take much code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int is_mmaped(void *ptr, size_t length) {
    FILE *file = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    char line[1024];
    int result = 0;
    while (!feof(file)) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line) / sizeof(char), file) == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        unsigned long start, end;
        if (sscanf(line, "%lx-%lx", &start, &end) != 2) {
            continue; // could not parse. fail gracefully and try again on the next line.
        }
        unsigned long ptri = (long) ptr;
        if (ptri >= start && ptri + length <= end) {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return result;
}
```

And some tests:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *test = mmap(NULL, 16384, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    printf("T %d\n", is_mmaped(test, 16384));
    printf("F %d\n", is_mmaped(test, 16385));
    printf("F %d\n", is_mmaped(test + 1, 16384));
    printf("T %d\n", is_mmaped(test, 1024));
    printf("T %d\n", is_mmaped(test, 256));
    printf("T %d\n", is_mmaped(test, 8));
    printf("T %d\n", is_mmaped(test + 16383, 1));
    munmap(test, 16384);
    printf("F %d\n", is_mmaped(test, 16384));

    printf("T %d\n", is_mmaped(main, 32));
    return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
T 1
F 0
F 0
T 1
T 1
T 1
T 1
F 0
T 1
```

as expected.